# IP address assignment without DNS, without DHCP server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I configured a DNS server with static IP configuration with named service on Centos 7. Servers are currently running in an environment without DHCP.

1. `hostname1`: ip1
2. `hostname2`: ip2
3. Etc.

If the machine with the hostname `hostnmame1` pops, is it possible for the DNS to assign its right IP without a DHCP server (and without having to define the static IP in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`)? I would prefer not to add a DHCP server if it exists a simpler way to associate hostname with the corresponding IP defined in my DNS configuration.

I assume machines have the DNS server defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: DNS doesn’t assign IP addresses. DHCP does.

Comment: So I am forced to install a DHCP server for such a simple thing?

Comment: A simple SOHO router can do DHCP too

Comment: “such a simple thing?” I would point out that pretty much every network on the planet has some sort of DHCP services running. But, no you’re not forced to use one, just use static IP addresses. Otherwise you’ll need DHCP. DNS doesn’t do what you are asking.

Comment: OP, what you are probably missing is this. On boot up, the server doesn't know its own address, so it cannot talk "normal" TCP/UDP protocols like DNS. DHCP is a very special protocol mainly in this respect: it can still be used even if you don't know your own IP address.

Comment: @Appleoddity On networks connecting end-users it is pretty common to use DHCP. But simpler setups are possible since a network with router advertisements and no DHCP server will cover the needs of end-users who don't need the advanced features provided by DHCP. On networks hosting servers static configuration is more common than dynamic configuration, so those usually only have DHCP if they need it for OS installs or booting recovery images. In normal operation a server will usually boot without needing DHCP.

Comment: @kasperd I’m not sure why you are telling me this? It doesn’t really pertain to the question. Router advertisements only exist with IPv6. For IPv4 you have DHCP, APIPA, or Static addressing for options. But that doesn’t really apply to the question as DNS still doesn’t hand out IP addresses in any scenario which is what was asked.

Comment: @Appleoddity I find the question quite unclear, so I can't say for sure what applies to the question and what does not. However the question does appear to be about a server running in an environment without DHCP. Thus it is relevant that that servers in normal operation usually don't rely on DHCP.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, servers are currently running in an environment without DHCP. I would prefer not to add a DHCP server if it exists a simpler way to associate hostname with the corresponding IP defined in my DNS configuration. I will edit the question then.

Comment: @Ninroot It is still unclear to me what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

**DNS Servers:**
Translates hostnames to ip address 
*example when you type serverfault.com in browser its gets translated or resolves to ip address which is stored in DNS server database and then the server serves the requested page and serevrfault.com page is opened.
The DNS server is the translator between the hostname and IP address.*

DNS servers can be deployed inhouse or we can use ISP or public DNS servers, example 8.8.8.8 is a DNS ip of google

**DHCP Servers:**
DHCP Server automatically provides and assigns IP addresses, default gateways and other network parameters to client devices. It relies on the standard protocol known as Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol or DHCP to respond to broadcast queries by clients.

Basic home/office routers have inbuild DHCP server which assigns ip to laptop/systems when connected via ethernet or wifi

Answer (score 0):

I think zeroconf/bonjour/avahi and link-local addresses may be something to consider in this scenario. But I never used it (I use my own DHCP and DNS server) so cannot provide any details :(.